# Django вывести данные в list_display

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Здравствуйте, новичок в `Django` недавно начал изучать, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, 
встала такая задача, вывести все данные из таблиц к примеру по `id` в админ панели `django` т.е.
существуют 3 модели к примеру

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    client_familia = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    pol = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)

class Jurnal(models.Model):
    poseshenie = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    data_poseshenia = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_poseshenia = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Uslugi(models.Model):
    abonement = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, models.DO_NOTHING)
    kol_zan = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    kol_mes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    data_zakaza = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    data_zakaza_do = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

возможно ли вывести на странице клиенты в админке (скриншот 1) , данные с таблицы `uslugi` , чтобы выводилась информация о последней заказанной услуге.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, значение находится в другой таблице, самих услуг будет n количество, но активна лишь только последняя, вот как именно вывести в `list_display` последнее активное значение(скриншот 2) из модели `Uslugi.data_zakaza`

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('client_id', 'client_name', 'client_familia', 'pol')
```

и еще вопрос можно ли поменять порядок при добавлении элементов, чтобы первая была кнопка добавить=>новая строка=> и тд. (скриншот2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поля в `list_display` могут быть callable, а значит можно [создать поле-функцию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client_id', 'client_name', 'client_familia', 'pol', 'usluga')

    def usluga(self, obj):
        return obj.uslugi_set.last()
    uslugi.short_description = u'Последняя услуга'
```

Не забудьте только в модели `Uslugi` определить метод преобразования в строку и задать порядок сортировки.

А чтобы переместить вверх элемент управления формсетом и формы добавления нового инлайна, в папке `templates` вашего проекта создайте папку `admin`, в ней папку `edit_inline`, скопируйте в неё шаблон `stacked.html` из пакета django и измените его по своему усмотрению.