# Как сравнить даты в Django и выделить строку в таблице Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

подскажите пожалуйста, к примеру есть вот такая модель в Django:

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Имя')
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Отчество')
    dopog = models.DateField(auto_now=False, verbose_name='Дата окончания ДОПОГ')
    international_dopusk = models.DateField(auto_now=False, verbose_name='Дата окончания международного допуска')
```

Как можно сравнить дату в DateField с текущей датой? Если Дата в DateFiled == Текущая дата - месяц, то выделить строку с этой записью в Админке Django.
Прошу прощения за возможно глупый вопрос, начал только изучать Django, и многое еще для меня непонятно
[image: Выделить строку в таблице в БД Django, если дата в DateField подходит условию]

Comment: Сравнить очень просто: `объект.dopog == datetime.date.today()`. А вот что за «выделить строку» — решительно непонятно

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за ответ, попробовал: На счет выделения строки прикрепил картинку, надеюсь так более понятно будет. Если выполняется условие, то строка в бд, у которой истек срок должна выделиться красным цветом, ну типа того

Comment: А просто столбца со значком или фильтр вам не хватит? Их делать намного проще, чем пытаться вмешаться в стили админки

Comment: @andreymal, этого тоже будет достаточно, подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовывается ?

Comment: Добавление столбца — [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658113) и [вот](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) и [вот](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display) (из функции верните `True` или `False`, тогда на его месте нарисуется значок), а фильтр — наверное [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951341) и [вот](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/filters/) (в lookups можно прописать значения вроде «Истек» и «Не истек», а в queryset выбрать объекты по значению)

Comment: @andreymal, огромное вам спасибо!!!!